# The "multiple" boolean appears to be ignored in a Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony

I have defined a Symfony 3.3 form type called ContactType. In my buildForm definition, I have changed this ...

```
        ->add('attachment',
            FileType::class,
            array('label' => 'File to upload',
                'required' => false))
```

... to this ...

```
        ->add('attachment',
            FileType::class,
            array('label' => 'File to upload',
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true))
```

... but the form still only shows one "choose file" box, without adding any others after I upload a file.

**How do I get my form to present a second "choose file" box after the first file is uploaded?**

For reference, here is the relevant part of my Twig template as it exists now:

```
<div>
    {{ form_widget(form.attachment) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.attachment) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I too faced such a task. I used Collection of Forms.

```
 ->add('attachments', 'collection', array(
  'type'   => 'file',
  'options'  => array(
    'required'  => false,
  ),
));
```

see also an example in the official documentation
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thanks, but this results in `The options "options", "type" do not exist. `

Comment: Aha -- it wanted entry_type and entry_options

Comment: But even after I add those, I find that no box is showing up. How did your Twig code look?

Comment: Sorry. I gave the example from project on Symfony2. In the Symfony3 will be different. Use an example from the documentation

Comment: <ul class="files">
        
        {% for file in form.files %}
            <li>{{ form_row(file.name) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>